# Powershell Studio 2016 and SQL updates | SQL queries with joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

So i have a very simple table in SQL Server (3 columns) and Im using 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' to query the table for info and put into various form fields. That works fine so the basic premise of connecting to a database with the syntax im using seems on point.

However I find then when i change the query portion of the cmdlet to 'UPDATE' values where whatever ... the database doesnt update. However if i run the same code in Powershell ISE it updates fine.

Similarly when i try to pull data from a set of tables using joins, the query works fine in PS ISE, but in code for PS Studio it doesnt fill a variable with results as my previous successful Invoke-Sqlcmd did.

Code that works in PS Studio:

```
$QueryResult = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'server\instance' -Database 'Hardware' -Query "SELECT * FROM allocation where empno = $emp"
```

Code that doesnt work in PS Studio but does work in ISE:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'Server\instance' -Database 'Hardware' -Query "Update dbo.allocation set MaxAllowed = $updateinputint where empno = $emp"
```

Code that works in ISE but not in PS Studio with joins:

```
$sqlcmd2 = "select dbo.CurrentLocation.Location, dbo.HwTable.HWCode, dbo.HwTable.HWDesc, COUNT(*) AS [COUNT]
    from dbo.CurrentLocation
    JOIN
    dbo.MainTable on dbo.CurrentLocation.number = dbo.MainTable.Number
    JOIN
    dbo.HwTable on dbo.MainTable.HWCode = dbo.HwTable.HWCode
    Where  dbo.CurrentLocation.Location = HO
    Group  by
    dbo.CurrentLocation.Location, dbo.HwTable.HWCode, dbo.HwTable.HWDesc"

    $queryresult2 = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'server\instance' -Database 'Hardware' -Query $sqlcmd2
```

At first the last query didnt work in ISE until i removed aliases, then it worked fine. Does PS Studio have some restrictions? Or am i missing a trick? There are no error messages, debugging passes over the lines fine but the variables show to hold nothing, or where inserting, the database doesnt update.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: I apologise for the formatting it looked a lot better in the preview.

Comment: what you mean by *doesn't work* actually?

Comment: The $queryresult2 doesnt get any data, it's just null.

Comment: What if you run the query directly in SSMS ... does it returns records

Comment: yes for all queries

Comment: I had a similar issue a while ago. My SQL Queries would work in SSMS, and when I ran them directly in ISE or called them from ISE, but would fail when ran as a scheduled task. I  ended up saving SQL queries, and calling them from PS in a batch file. It's a messy workaround, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to 'white space' even when i edited the query to sit on one line in order to omit any carriage returns or tabbed space it still wouldnt work. Apparently powershell studio doesnt like lengthy strings. Encapsulating the query string with @querytext@ made it work. Debug variable contents at run time looked identical with and without the @ symbols but with made it work.